# Java date format convert on Android

Tags: java, android, date

I have date String as below:

```
Fri, 19 Jul 2013 01:30:22 GMT
Thu, 12 Sep 2013 19:19:18 GMT
```

And I want to convert to below format:

```
2013/07/19 01:30:22
2013/09/12 19:19:18
```

At first, I use below code to parse date:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("Fri, 23 Aug 2013 01:10:35 GMT");
```

But it show below exception on line `Date date = dateFormat.parse("Fri, 23 Aug 2013 01:10:35 GMT");`:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 23 Aug 2013 01:10:35 GMT" (at offset 0)
```

How can I modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

your default language is probably not English and does not accept Fri and Aug

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
String dateString = "Fri, 19 Jul 2013 01:30:22 GMT";

    SimpleDateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
                .parse(dateString);
        Log.e("result", "Date:" + simple.format(date));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String DateStr="Fri, 19 Jul 2013 01:30:22 GMT";
    SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(DateStr); 
System.out.println(sim.format(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make like this.

```
String newDate = date.getYear()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getDay() and ect.
```

or you can write your own convert method

```
String myConvert(Date date)
{
return date.getYear()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getDay()+ect.
}
```

Comment: Methods `date.getYear()`, `date.getMonth()` etc. are **deprecated**. See Java 7 docs [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: I'd like to use java.util.Calendar

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("Fri, 23 Aug 2013 01:10:35 GMT");
String formattedString=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").
                                                     format(date).toString();
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String           dateStr = "Fri, 19 Jul 2013 01:30:22 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sdf     = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date             date    = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(dateStr); 
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
date.parse("Fri, 19 Jul 2013 01:30:22 GMT");
String newDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with "format" :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
String date = "";
try {
   date = dateFormat.format("Fri, 23 Aug 2013 01:10:35 GMT");
} catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This does not compile (quotation marks left out). Furthermore, it is not really different from what the OP tried. The right answer is to select english locale.