# SimpleDateFormat not parsing

Tags: java, simpledateformat

There are a million threads about the `SimpleDateFormat` class out there and I am having trouble, too:

Here's my little test code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateReader = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd LLL YYYY HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    date.setTime(dateReader.parse(dateReader.format(date.getTime())));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One might think, that the current date in the correct format would be parsed correctly and this would run through without trouble but instead I get an exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 11 Aug 2017 15:44:48 +0200"`

Finally, I just want to parse a date like "Thu, 03 Aug 2017 20:10:00 +0200". I believe I have the right pattern for that.

I have no clue right now, what is wrong with it.

**EDIT**
The **difference** to the other questions is the pattern used. If you see the answer it shows that the pattern has been used incorrectly whereas most other questions have a totally wrong pattern or the wrong local. There might be a duplicate out there somewhere – but out of these many similarly named questions it is possibly faster to simply leave this as an own question.

Comment: try `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`

Comment: What is `LLL` supposed to do? Don't see it in the options in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @RobinTopper You point to the docs for JDK 7; see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for JDK 8. But it's not explained very clearly...

Comment: @Jesper My bad ... But indeed, terrible explanation of `L`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java date format convert on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899991/java-date-format-convert-on-android)

Comment: Thank you for your help and especially to the down votes, reminding me what a risk it is to ask a question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is on the year format use 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY'.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateReader = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
  dateReader.parse("Thu, 03 Aug 2017 20:10:00 +0200");
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The problem is also the month, you wright correctly in your answer `MMM`, but he used `LLL`. By the way your answer is correct +1

Comment: Yes, indeed it was the wrong month format. Maybe someone could give a better explaination than the Java Docs when to use `L` and when `M`?

Comment: @JSHelp If you set a `DateFormatSymbols` to the formatter (in the constructor `SimpleDateFormat(String, DateFormatSymbols)` or calling  `setDateFormatSymbols(DateFormatSymbols)`), the pattern `M` will use the month names defined in the `DateFormatSymbols` object, while `L` will ignore it and use the java built-in names. If you don't set a `DateFormatSymbols`, both `L` and `M` will produce the same output.